# How to dispatch Javascript custom events from a custom object

Tags: javascript, custom-events

I have 2 scripts (Extremely simplified examples below) - The first controls the display of a specified nav menu on a page and it us used in several places for different kinds of menus.

```
const NavMenu = function(selector) {
  this.menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(`${selector} li > a`);
  let This = this;      
  This.menuItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', e => {
        item.classList.toggle('selected'); 
    });
  });
}

const myNavMenu = new NavMenu('.menu-wrap');
```

The other is used for 1 specific purpose on a specific page containing a menu that is controlled by the 1st script.

```
(function () {
   const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-wrap li > a');
   menuItems.forEach(item => {
     item.addEventListener('click', e => {
         const selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-wrap li > a.selected');
         let str = '';
         if(selectedItems.length) {
           selectedItems.forEach((item, i) => {
             str += `${item.textContent} `;
           });
           document.querySelector('#results').innerText = `Selected: ${str}`;
         }
       });
   });
 })();
```

As you can see, the 2nd script has a click handler that performs an action based on the state of each menu item ("selected" or not). Since that state is set by the 1st script, this only works if 1st script's click handler runs BEFORE the 2nd.

I created a version where I force the 2nd script's click handler to run first(via `setTimeout`). Clicking on the items, you can see that the resulting text does not match.
https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/GROXmrq

Because the 1st script is used in many other places, it needs to run independently of any other script, otherwise I would have just combined the 2.

I *think* a custom event is the answer here. i implemented one here: https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/xxPaqzJ from an example I found, but I have no idea if this is the correct way to do it. It works, but that doesn't mean a ton...

I'd think the event should be somehow tied to the `NavMenu` object, but I couldn't get it to dispatch from anything other than `window` or `document` or another DOM element. Can anyone point me in the right direction for a way that I can do something like: `myMenu.addEventListener('done', e => //do some stuff)` rather than having it attached to `window`? Or if I'm way off to even begin with, feel free to let me know as much too.

I know this is kind of built into jQuery, but this needs to stay Vanilla JavaScript - thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @Bergi - yes I looked there - it does not talk about dispatching from a custom (non-DOM node object)...

Comment: But why not dispatch it from the `menuItem` that has been clicked? No, you cannot dispatch event from arbitrary objects (that don't implement `EventTarget`). You could of course easily write your own callback logic, like `this.onDone?.(…);` and `NavMenu.onDone = e => { … };`, no need to use DOM event on non-DOM objects.

Comment: dispatching from the `menuItem` as you suggested... not so much for my actual situation, but that's for me to figure out. the callback logic seems like it may work, but i can't seem to figure it out. An example would be great. I can post a new question with more info on what i've tried, if that makes more sense.

Comment: My bad. Meant to say... dispatching from the `menuItem` as you suggested **worked great for this example**... not so much for my actual situation,

Comment: I have not got the time today to write a complete answer, but what about setting up a *delegated click-event-handling*. I. e. an event handler being attached to the body of your page?The script  could filter out the relevant situations it needs to react upon by comparing `ev.target` to your selectors and - most of all - you can make sure that "script1" actions are always run *before* "script2" actions.

Comment: @Daveh0 Yes, you might want to post a new, different question, if your current post doesn't describe your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an event emitter class instead that I found (and learned a lot from) in [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-your-own-event-emitter-in-javascript-fbd5db2447c4). As @Bergi stated in a comment on the OP, events cannot be attached to a plain object. Since Script 1 can be used anywhere in all different situations, this seemed most standard and logical to me.

It's super simple...

1. Create an instance of the emitter in Script 1:
   `This.emitter = new MyEventEmitter();`
2. Emit events wherever necessary with whatever data is appropriate (in Script 1):
   `This.emitter.emit("done", item);`
3. "Listen" for the event and handle appropriately in Script 2:
   `NavMenu.emitter.on("done", menuItem => {...});`

Here's the whole thing which you can see working in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/GROXmrq).

```
class MyEventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this._events = {};
  }

  on(name, listener) {
    if (!this._events[name]) {
      this._events[name] = [];
    }
    this._events[name].push(listener);
  }

  removeListener(name, listenerToRemove) {
    if (!this._events[name]) {
      throw new Error(
        `Can't remove a listener. Event "${name}" doesn't exits.`
      );
    }
    const filterListeners = (listener) => listener !== listenerToRemove;
    this._events[name] = this._events[name].filter(filterListeners);
  }

  emit(name, data) {
    if (!this._events[name]) {
      throw new Error(`Can't emit an event. Event "${name}" doesn't exits.`);
    }
    const fireCallbacks = (callback) => {
      callback(data);
    };
    this._events[name].forEach(fireCallbacks);
  }
}

const NavMenu = function (selector) {
  this.menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(`${selector} li > a`);
  let This = this;
  This.emitter = new MyEventEmitter();
  This.menuItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        item.classList.toggle("selected");
        This.emitter.emit("done", item);
    });
  });
};

const myNavMenu = new NavMenu(".menu-wrap");

(function (NavMenu) {
  const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-wrap li > a");
  menuItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      NavMenu.emitter.on("done", (menuItem) => {
        const selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll(
          ".menu-wrap li > a.selected"
        );
        let str = "Selected: ";
        if (selectedItems.length) {
          selectedItems.forEach((item, i) => {
            str += `${item.textContent} `;
          });
        } else {
          str += `none`;
        }
        document.querySelector("#results").innerText = `${str}`;
      });
    });
  });
})(myNavMenu);
```