# How to make a Javascript class or object an event dispatcher?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create an object or class that can be an event dispatcher, even if it is hacky?

There is this question where the answer was to create an emitter:
[How to dispatch Javascript custom events from a custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272883/how-to-dispatch-javascript-custom-events-from-a-custom-object)

I don't want to create an emitter. I'd rather misuse an existing object as long as it can dispatch normal events. This is a basic feature in other languages.

Here is example code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class MyApp extends EventDispatcher {
   constructor () {
      
   }
}

var myApp = new MyApp();
myApp.addEventListener("initialized", function(event) { console.log('initialized') }); 
myApp.dispatchEvent(new Event("initialized"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
class MyApp extends EventTarget {
  static initialized = new Event('initialized')
}

const myApp = new MyApp()

myApp.addEventListener("initialized", () => {
  console.log('initialized')
})

myApp.dispatchEvent(MyApp.initialized);
```